# How to split a auto-renewable subscriptions to accounts?

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, subscription, apple-id

My application has a monthly and year auto-renewal subscription. At the moment, when testing in the Sandbox, I had problems (All actions are carried out on one Apple ID):

1. **User A** is registered in the application.
2. **User A** bought a monthly subscription.
3. **User A** exits the application.
4. **User B** is also registered in the application and wants to buy a monthly subscription.
5. A message appears that **the subscription has already been purchased**.

What could be the reason? Is 1 Apple ID used for 2 accounts in the app? How can this be solved?

P. S. I work with my server.

Answer (score 1):

In-App Purchases tied to Apple ID. You must log-in under different apple id on your device to buy subscription again.

Comment: No, you can't. It's a privacy element like the UDID.

Comment: @MikhailTseitlin Apple doesn't know anything about your app specific accounts, it only knows about the signed in iTunes account on the device. From their point of view, User A and User B are the same. Every app has this limitation, even the biggest apps like Netflix, Tinder, Spotify, etc.